# How to transfer realsense data via ROS to other Device(s)

Tags: c++, device, communication, ros, realsense

I want to make the program under

" catkin_ws/src/realsense-ros-3.2.13/realsense2_camera "

directory from the "ros wrapper site" transfer realsense data to other devices.

I've chosen to use ".cpp file" since I've already made the program which uses C++ and realsense camera.

I want to know the relationships of the files inside " realsense2_camera/src " directory
and how and where the executable files appears after catkin_make etc., because I want to remodel that file(s),if it's able to transfer the realsense data to other Devices to do it.

I think it's related with roscpp_tutorials, rospy_tutorials and beginner_tutorials' Publisher and Subscriber Programs and I was able to make Publisher and Subscriber Programs communicating with different Devices, though I don't know about the theory of why they run. (how and where the executable files appears)

---

### Environment

Device OS: ubuntu 18.04
Device HW: Jetson nano
rosdistro: melodic
python: Python 2.7.17
Realsense ROS Wrapper: 2.2.13
Realsense Viewer Version: 2.34.0
Camera: D435
D435 Firmware: 5.12.03.00

Comment: Let me check if this is correct: you _do_ want to use ros, and you want to use the data coming from a realsense? Why don't you use their pre-built nodes & launch files? Just call the relevant launch file from your main.launch file, and subscribe to the relevant output (rgb, depth, calibration, compressed data...) (Nj posting your working env).

Comment: Or is your confusion on how ros works? How data is passed between "nodes" for computation? Programming in ros is creating launch files, which are the main() functions. The "nodes" are like functions, with inputs (subscribers) outputs (publishers) with well-defined types (msgs), where the "variables" they're writing to are the "topics". So in your launch file, if you include the node/launch file they provide, you have a node (function) that reads from your device & provides data to the "camera" topic (variable) (and subtopics) and other nodes you write can subscribe to these topics & do math.

Comment: > you do want to use ros, and you want to use the data coming from a realsense?
Yes, that's right.
> Just call the relevant launch file from your main.launch file, and subscribe to the relevant output
I think there is no "main.launch" file precisely in realsense2_camera directory,
but I understand that subscribing mechanism.

Comment: I meant, in your launch file, the launch file that is your "main executable". Have you tried `<include>`'ing one of the launch files, or running one of them? If you've read the [realsense-ros/README](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros), it lists some demos to see that the camera is working & get the topics being published. I'm understanding "transfer to other devices" to mean have other programs subscribe to these topics, correct me if I'm wrong. To your other question, source code is in catkin_ws/src, the build files in build/, and the built executables/headers in devel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your information.

I've been wandering why I couldn't get the D435's Data, but I solved it.

Starting "realsense-viewer" when "roslaunch" the ".launch file" and restarting the "Terminal" SEVERAL TIME can make "default .launch file" launch, so re-writing the "launch file" might be able to move the C++/Python file(s).

And I think your " include 'ing method" will make the problem simple to solve.